# Oracle DB select query returning the data in form of array instead of json array using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, oracle

My DB select result

```
{
        "metaData": [
            {
                "name": "CUSTOMERID"
            },
            {
                "name": "NAME"
            },
            {
                "name": "EMAILID"
            },
            {
                "name": "PHONE_NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "name": "CREATED_AT"
            },
            {
                "name": "ACC_STATUS"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            [
                "62c697be-b0b8-4f90-a014-149c1c175303",
                "ratan uday kumar",
                "uday@evontex.com",
                "+91781891",
                "2018-06-04T10:20:55.505Z",
                0
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Expected Data

```
[
    {
        "CUSTOMERID": "62c697be-b0b8-4f90-a014-149c1c175303",
        "NAME": "ratan uday kumar",
        "EMAILID": "uday@evontex.com",
        "PHONE_NUMBER": "+91781891",
        "CREATED_AT": "2018-06-04T10:20:55.505Z",
        "ACC_STATUS": 0
    }
]
```

I am using nodejs [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) package

Is there any method to get result in json array or do manually i have to write json array function???

The Answer is by setting the Output format of response to object provided by @**torsten link**

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
```

The above answer have worked for me

Comment: downvote for not even using the documentation behind the link you provided...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most probably look for "oracledb.outFormat". Check the [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdboutformat) of this feature.

> 3.2.14 oracledb.outFormat

> The format of query rows fetched when using connection.execute() or connection.queryStream().
> It affects both ResultSet and non-ResultSet queries.
> It can be used for top level queries and REF CURSOR output.

> This can be either of the Oracledb constants oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_ARRAY or oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT. The **default value is oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_ARRAY** which is more efficient. The older, equivalent constants oracledb.ARRAY and oracledb.OBJECT are deprecated.

Just add one line should already help:

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
```

Comment: FYI the default value is now oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_ARRAY instead of oracledb.ARRAY, If specified as oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT, each row is fetched as a JavaScript object. The older, equivalent constants oracledb.ARRAY and oracledb.OBJECT are deprecated.

Comment: Modified answer to follow current documentation.