# Node JS and oracledb returning name of columns instead of values

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

off the bat I have looked and tried the following

```
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679120/oracle-db-select-query-returning-the-data-in-form-of-array-instead-of-json-array
```

^ this is my exact same problem and I have tried the solution and it doesn't work for me.

I also copied the exact same code for as the doucmentation

```
     https://github.com/oracle/node-   oracledb/blob/main/examples/example.js#L32:~:text=sql%20%3D%20%60SELECT%20*%20FROM%20no_example%60%3B,rows%2C%20%7B%20depth%3A%20null%20%7D)%3B]
```

and it still doesn't work.

Below is my code which I am using with node v19.3.0, and oracledb 5.5 (please note it does connect to the DB correctly)

```
      if (err) {
         console.error(err.message);
         return;
      }
      else{
       options = {
        outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,   // query result format
         //extendedMetaData: true               // get extra metadata
       };
       let query = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS";
       binds = {};
       const result = await connection.execute(query, binds, options); 
       console.log(result);
       doRelease(connection);
      }
```

from this the output is

```
     {
       metaData: [ { name: 'USERNAME' }, { name: 'TOKENS' }, { name: 'PASSWORD' } ],
       rows: []
     }
    Connection released
```

However if I run this exact same query in sql developer (obviously connected to the same DB and with same credentials) I get all accounts... Does anyone know what may be causing this? I am trying to get the values of the fields!

The expected output for this should have been the data inside the table which is 'test' 20, 'test@gmail.com'

Comment: "Doesn't work" tells exactly nothing about actual issue. Does it return the data you didn't expect? Does it throw an error? What error?

Comment: Doesn't work as instead of returning the values from the table it returns the column names... The expected out put should be 'test1', 20, 'test1@gmail.com'
Since theres only 1 row in the table

Comment: Did you check the [reference documentation](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#select-statements)? *By default, queries are handled as ‘direct fetches’, meaning all results are returned in the callback `result.rows` property*

Comment: Yes, as you can see the rows array in the output is always empty.

Comment: My guess is that you've inserted rows into your table but haven't `COMMIT`ted the transaction in SQL Developer. Until you do commit. only the SQL Developer session can see the rows you've inserted.